# Error when calling EJB from managed bean

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am having an issue when calling EJB from a dynamic web application. I'm using Eclipse Kepler for development.

The error that I'm having is when I **run IN DEBUG MODE** the application and the EJB is called I get this error:

[image]

with no other details, but if I see the name of the tab the error is in, I can see the full text, `EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(Ojbect, Mehtod, Object[])`

[image]

The code that I use to call the EJB is:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
@EJB
private UserSessionBeanLocal userSessionBean;
@EJB
private DvdSessionBeanLocal dvdSessionBean;
private int id;
private String username;
private String password;

public UserBean(){
}

public String login(){
    String response = null;
    userSessionBean.userLogin(username, password);
    try {
        response = userSessionBean.userLogin(username, password);
    } catch (EJBException e) {
        response = e.getMessage();
    }
return response;
}
```

**Edits:**

1. I am using Maven
2. pom.xml from client level

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>DvdClient</groupId>
   <artifactId>DvdClient</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <build>
       <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.7</source>
                   <target>1.7</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.3</version>
               <configuration>
                   <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>test1</groupId>
           <artifactId>DvdTest</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
3. DvdTest is my EJB application
4. I am using Glassfish 4.0 as my Application Server
5. This is the stack trace when I run the application (not in debug mode):

   ```
   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
   at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
   at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
   Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy460.userLogin(Unknown Source)
   at businessSession.__EJB31_Generated__UserSessionBean__Intf____Bean__.userLogin(Unknown Source)
   at myBeans.UserBean.login(UserBean.java:37)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
   at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
   at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
   at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
   at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
   at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
   at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
   at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
   ... 35 more
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
   at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
   at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:171)
   at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:455)
   at businessSession.UserSessionBean.findAll(UserSessionBean.java:77)
   at businessSession.UserSessionBean.userLogin(UserSessionBean.java:55)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
   at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
   at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
   at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
   at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
   at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
   ... 52 more
   ```
6. No EJB .jar files under DvdTest folder when I press the error button `Edit Source Lookup Path` [image]
7. pom.xml of EJB module

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>test1</groupId>
   <artifactId>DvdTest</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>5.1.26</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
           <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
           <artifactId>ejb31-api-experimental</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.4</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.transaction</artifactId>
           <version>10.0-b28</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.1</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
8. declaration of EJB module

Comment: how is your ejb declared?, which AS are you using?, are you using Maven/Ant, how looks your POM?

Comment: @Chechus I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused. What does AS stand for?

Comment: Application server, tomEE/Glassfish/Websphere/Weblogic....

Comment: @Chechus Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe is the way how your are adding the dependency to the war file: try this change to the POM

POM - WAR:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>test1</groupId>
    <artifactId>DvdTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>ejb</type>     --------ADD THIS LINE
</dependency>
```

POM - EJB:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test1</groupId>
<artifactId>DvdTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>   --------ADD THIS LINE
```

And according to the log, you should declare a persistence unit (for JPA in a persistence.xml, hibernate should support it)

Comment: I get the same error. I can't understand what references I am missing or what I am pointing at incorrectly.

Comment: have you tested the ejb module before?, are you sure that is working properly?

Comment: It appears that when I press `Edit Lookup Path` button, it only sees the .jar files in the DvdTest folder (my EJB project), but no EJB .jar files.

Comment: How can I separately test the EJB module?

Comment: well, you could use tools like Arquillian, but meanwhile, because you are not sure if is working properly, can you show the POM  of the EJB module and the declaration of the ejb??

Comment: Reading in detail the log, thereis no persistence unit... Please show your persistence.xml file!!

Comment: I have no `persistence.xml` file, I have used hibernate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47420/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-chechus)

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
```

looks like your UserSessionBean cannot gain access to a DB when you call userLogin

```
UserSessionBean.userLogin(UserSessionBean.java:55)
```

I would suggest you to check the following:

- take a look at your persistance.xml and check if everything is on its place there
- check if you created all necessary resources in your Glassfish application server (datasource/pool). If you are using pooling, you may also want to try to ping your connection pool from application server web console and see if it works
- check if you database is up and available